# How to send GET request with login (user:pass) from a button?

Tags: html, ajax, authentication, passwords, get

I want a button on a webpage that, when pressed, does the equivalent of entering this url in the browser and hitting enter.

http://user:pass@www.example.com/example/button_24

The code below gives me the button but it seems that it doesn't want to pass the credentials, firebug says this:

Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012

if i remove the credentials it says 401 Unauthorized

Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function simpleAjax()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("Divku").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://user:pass@www.example.com/example/button_24",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="simpleAjax()">Request data</button>
<div id="Divku"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

new code

```
<head> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" >  </head>
<img alt="screenshot" src="http://a:a@www.example.com/example/screenshot.jpg">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function simpleAjax()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("Divku").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic YTph');
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.example.com/example/button_24",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="simpleAjax()">Volume Up</button>
<div id="Divku"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to `setRequestHeader` on the AJAX object and supply the **Authentication** header instead of passing it in the URL. Remember the server is looking for the header

```
Authorization: Basic abc123==
```

(or some facsimile).

Maybe check out [this link](http://www.aswinanand.com/2009/01/http-basic-authentication-using-ajax/) on supplying credentials with AJAX requests?

ALSO, MDN on [setRequestHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest#setRequestHeader%28%29) method.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a real amateur. I copied all this code from a webpage I found in a google search on how to make a button.  I dont even know what ajax is. That link on supplying credentials makes no sense to me unfortunately.

Comment: Basically, before your `xmlhttp.open` call, you need something like `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic abc123==');` where `abc123==` is a base-64 encoded version of the username, a single colon (`:`) then the password combined.

Comment: so there is some translation that will turn user:pass into a string that I replace "abc123==" with?

Comment: Ok, so I got the translation of the user:pass which is a:a. now my code looks like this and it throws this error uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/User/Desktop/webkeyautoref.html :: simpleAjax :: line 23" data: no]

Comment: @max: is your username and password encoded? Or are you just passing `Basic a:a` to the setRequestHeader method?

Comment: I encoded it to YTph using this http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Comment: any other ideas? I'm still quite stuck.

Comment: Just noticed that the button does work if I press it in IE, so it seems the problem is only with firefox. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: @max: is the website hosting the page and the page you're trying to request with ajax on the same domain?

Comment: @max: re-order the `setRequestHeader` and `open` calls, so the connection is opened first, then the header is set. Does that help?

Comment: yeah, I had to do that to get it to stop giving errors. But still it doesnt work in FF, only IE. Also, the pages are in different domains. I'm not set on using this particular method, im open to doing somthing else if there is a copy paste way to do it...

Comment: here is what the developer recomends but I dont understand this curl thing "curl --digest http://username:password@phone's_address/injkey -d "Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép""

Comment: @max: You're always going to have trouble crossing the domain boundary with AJAX. For security purposes a page residing on abc.com can't "ping" a page on def.com without some kind of security bypass. So, what the author is probably recommending is to do the call from within server code or perform the action server-side in some fashion.

Comment: I dont mind not using ajax, I just dont really know what I'm doing. What should I look into? I see php comming up in my searches about this. Would that be able to do it? This dev code is part of an api so I assume that it's meant to come from an external application, no?

Comment: @Max: I'd need more insight in to what you're trying to achieve. Server language (are these regular HTML pages, PHP, ASP, etc.) Also, what is the point of making the authenticated calls--does the API require authentication? Is it something you can re-route through a local server page (so the client can use AJAX and the server handles all the "dirty" cross-domain authentication bits)?

Comment: Thanks brad, basically what im trying to do is to use this http://androidwebkey.com/ to send a command to my phone via a button on a web page. I have webserver that seems like it runs all the standare stuff. But the site I'm actually trying to make this work on is a "google site" that views my webpage in an iframe.